# JAXRS, JAXB implementation guide

Tags: java, xml

my requirement is: A form submit should trigger the LoginServlet, from which the username and password are passed to UserService.login. If the username and password are validated (if statement is fine) an user xml string should be returned. Do I need to use Jaxb or any other parser? using String builder is good approach?

I have used String builder as:

```
StringBuilder validUser = new StringBuilder();  
validUser.append("<username>");
validUser.append(username);
validUser.append("</username>");
validUser.append("<firstname>");
validUser.append("Jose");
validUser.append("</firstname>");
validUser.append("<lastname>");
validUser.append("Tom");
validUser.append("</lastname>");
validUser.append("</user>");
String result = validUser.toString();
```

From the above string i.e result, I need to get/display firstName i.e.Jose to the UI.
I tried with String index, not able to get exact result since user name is always changes or user name length is always varies.

Comment: why don't you XML parser instead of parsing text index based

Comment: Why not use DOM/SAX to work with XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JAXB implementation.

some of the references are:

1>[code geekers](http://javapapers.com/jee/jaxb-tutorial/)

2>[techferry](http://www.techferry.com/articles/jaxb-annotations.html)

3>[vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/)

4>[java papers](http://javapapers.com/jee/jaxb-tutorial/)

```
String USER_DETAILS_XML = "./user-details.xml";
String USER_ERROR_XML = "./user-error.xml";

    public String login(String username, String password)
                throws JAXBException, PropertyException, FileNotFoundException {        
                    User user = new User();
            InvalidUser invalidUser = new InvalidUser();

            if ((username !=null && password !=null)) {
                user.setUserName(username);
                user.setFirstName("Jose");
                user.setLastName("Tom");

                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
                Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
                marshaller.marshal(user, System.out);
                marshaller.marshal(user,new File(USER_DETAILS_XML));

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                User userResult = (User) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader(
                        USER_DETAILS_XML));
                return userResult.getFirstName();
            }
            else{
                invalidUser.setCode(400);
                invalidUser.setMessage("something wrong here");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InvalidUser.class);
                Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
                marshaller.marshal(invalidUser, System.out);
                marshaller.marshal(invalidUser, new File(USER_ERROR_XML));

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                InvalidUser invalidUserResult = (InvalidUser) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader(USER_ERROR_XML));
                return invalidUserResult.getMessage();
            }
}
```

User.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "userName", "firstName", "lastName" })
public class User{

    private String userName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ....get/set
```

}

InvalidUser.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "status")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "code", "message" })
public class InvalidUser {
    private int code;
    private String message;
    ...set/get
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, pay attention to the comments, XML parser is indeed the right way to go here.
But if you want just a quick fix for your code, so here you go, this snippet will extract the necessary info:

```
Matcher matcher =  Pattern.compile("<firstname>(.*?)</firstname>").matcher(result);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if this is an attempt to generate a valid XML through `StringBuilder`, your approach is quite debatable.

See also the comments to your question (by *Jigar Joshi* and *fnt*).

There are many APIs to build XMl programmatically. In your case, since it's a short document, I would suggest [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/).

Secondly, if you indulged in a lax approach and wanted to build your pseudo-xml through this methodology nonetheless, you would at least require to add the following line after your `StringBuilder` initialization (or as an argument to the constructor):

```
validUser.append("<user>");
```

or

```
StringBuilder validUser = new StringBuilder("<user>");
```

Finally, to "solve" your issue, you can use:

```
String xml = validUser.toString();
System.out.println(
    xml.substring(
        xml.indexOf("<firstname>") + 11, xml.indexOf("</firstname>")
    )
);
```

Comment: can I use JAXB instead of DOM?

Comment: Well ususally [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) is employed for binding XML to data classes, but yeah, if you have the data you can use whatever binding framework to serialize into XML.

Comment: my requirement is: A form submit should trigger the LoginServlet, from which the username and password are passed to UserService.login. If the username and password are validated (if statement is fine) an user xml string should be returned. Is this means, i.e string should be returned means I need to create String or i can use JAXB/DOM?

Comment: @akb again, you should use a serializer or a streamer or any proper data-representation framework to work with XML. From there to a `String` representation of the object in question, it's usually quite trivial.